How i can overrid diffrent properties according to stages like qa,production
How can I override diffrent properties according to stages like qa, production?
For qa I was using this in common-shared.properties -
spring.profiles.active=integrationqa and in integrationqa-shared
asset.server.url.prefix.internal=integrationqa-cmsstatic
database.user=postgres
local database password
database.password=*****
database.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
this connection URL assumes that it is connecting to a schema called broadleaf
database.url=****
On the qa server, it should take properties of qa but it's getting default common-shared.properties
Am I missing anything?

by using different .properties files for different environmetns and activating these with corresponding profiles - see externalized configuration. Downvoting for lack of research effort, see how to ask

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: How to read values from properties file?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
